# How to hide the datepicker after selecting a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap to pick the date and wants that it hides when user select the date . Here is my datepicker code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control datepicker" datepicker id="startdate2"  placeholder=" Due Date" name="due_date" >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control datepicker" datepicker id="startdate" placeholder=" Expire Date" name="expiry_date" >
</div>
```

And trying to hide by using this code.Could anyone help to aware me how it will work correctly.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#startdate2').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true
        });

        $('#startdate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }).on('change', function () {
            $('.datepicker').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I removed the tag PHP since neither the question nor the code has anything to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use You can use event `changedate()` :

```
$('#startdate2').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#startdate2').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true
        }).on('changeDate', function () {
            $('.datepicker').hide();
        });

        $('#startdate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        }).on('changeDate', function () {
            $('.datepicker').hide();
        });
    });
```

IF it not work try `blur()` instead of `hide()` :

```
$(this).blur();
```

Comment: No it's not working.. Can you please add the fiddle of this code?

Comment: did you try blur()

Comment: yesss i have tried it..That's why i want the fiddle of this code